# GData API "Cannot access the calendar you requested"

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, gdata, gdata-api

I maintain this Java open source project that syncs Lotus Notes calendar entries with Google Calendar:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/lngooglecalsync/

Around June 6, 2013 about eight users started getting the below error on 9 out of 10 tries. Notice that the HTML part of the response contains the message "Cannot access the calendar you requested". The rest of the HTML simply displays a colored version of the word "Google".

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Internal Server Error
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Error</title>
<style type="text/css">body {font-family: arial,sans-serif}</style></head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td rowspan="3" width="1%" nowrap><b><font face="times" size="10"><font color="#0039b6">G</font> <font color="#c41200">o</font> <font color="#f3c518">o</font> <font color="#0039b6">g</font> <font color="#30a72f">l</font> <font color="#c41200">e</font></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#3366cc"><font face="arial,sans-serif" color="#ffffff"><b>Error</b></font></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<blockquote>Cannot access the calendar you requested</blockquote>
<p></p>
<div style="background:#3366cc; width:1px; height:4px"></div></body></html>
```

Here is the getFeed() call that is causing the exception:

```
try {
   calendars = service.getFeed(mainCalendarFeedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
} catch (com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException ex) {
   calendars = null;    
   throw ex;
}
```

Prior to June 6, this problem didn't exist. Around the same time, Google made a calendar change to how they stored empty Location values. Previously they used null, now they use "". This broke my code initially, but now I handle both situations.

Also, a user reported that he had been successfully running a Coldfusion script for over a year that executes a simple http get operation on a private Google Calendar link. That script is now failing intermittently with the same problem.

Based on all this information, I think Google has changed something on their end that is now causing this intermittent problem. Most of the users (including me) don't ever see this exception, but I'd like to find a solution for the people experiencing the issue.

Any thoughts on how I can diagnose or fix the problem?

**UPDATE:** On 8/12/2013 all the users who were experiencing this problem said it stopped. So, we assume the problem was on Google's side and it has been fixed.